# How clear is my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

How clear is my post, "[How to prove this Darboux-like sum converges to zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637157/how-do-prove-this-darboux-like-sum-converges-to-zero)". Do you understand how to compute sums for specific $s$? Could you visualize my definitions? If there's anything unclear explain why and how you would explain it instead.

Edits: I made edits, to my [original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637157/how-do-prove-this-darboux-like-sum-converges-to-zero). Please explain whether you can fully visualize my definition. Do you understand how to make sums for specific $s$.

Edit: I am glad there are upvotes and more people responding. Can we say my post is officially clear or is there still confusion.

Comment: @amWhy This is a different question. Read carefully. In one question $A$ is $\left\{\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{2^y}+\frac{1}{2^z}:x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, in the other it is the cantor set. That's the difference between a countable set dense on infinite limit points and an uncountable set of lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: If you ask similar but substantially different questions explain the similarities and especially the differences. If this is not or cannot be done then as @amWhy explained, you possibly need to put more effort into this.